# How to find definition of DBpedia properties like `domain`, `range`, `comment`

Tags: properties, uri, dbpedia, prefix, knowledge-graph

These days I have been struggling to construct a new dataset with opensource dataset. And I have to decide the characteristics of property in DBpedia such as `symmetry`, `antisymmetry`, `transitivity`. At first, I need to gather information of properties like `domain`, `range`, `comment`.

I can find information of property those with a prefix `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` by visiting the full URI like below:
[image]
which contains detailed information of property which includes `domain`, `range`, and `comment`.

But when it comes to properties with prefix `http://dbpedia.org/property/`
[image]
It only contains `label` and `type`.

So I wonder how to find `domain`, `range`, and `comment` of properties those with prefix `http://dbpedia.org/property/`? And whether there is a file recording these information of properties? I mean it's would be easier for me to handle a file than visit webpage one by one to get the `domain`, `range`, and `comment` of properties.

Comment: Best path is probably to report issues on the relevant repository on GitHub -- likely the [DBpedia Ontology Issue tracker](https://github.com/dbpedia/ontology-tracker), where "we keep track of modification requests in the DBpedia Ontology", or possibly the [DBpedia Information Extraction Framework](https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework), the "software used to extract structured data from Wikipedia". You may prefer to start a conversation on the [DBpedia Forum](https://forum.dbpedia.org/), or to do some digging on the [DBpedia Wiki](https://www.dbpedia.org/).